# How to setState for all instances of the same component type in that component

Tags: reactjs

How to setState for all instances of the same component type in that component.

In ParentComponent

```
render() {
     return(
          <ChildComponent ... />
          <ChildComponent ... />
          <ChildComponent ... />
      );
}
```

In ChildComponent

```
//onClick Handler should set state of all instances
onClick() {
    this.setState({value: ''})
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). What is the root problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some `value` which is used by multiple child components, then the correct way is to take that value one level up (i.e. in parent) and pass that value to those child as `prop` so that all children share the same value. So maintain a `state` in parent and pass them as prop to children like this

```
onClick() {
  this.setState({value: ''})
}
render() {
     return(
          <ChildComponent value={this.state.value} onClick={this.onClick}... />
          <ChildComponent value={this.state.value} onClick={this.onClick}... />
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the same state in all of the child instances, I'd say that what you want to do is actually set the state in the parent, then pass that into all of the children as a prop. You'll need a click handler method in the parent, which you'll pass to the children as well.

Ok, I haven't tested this code, but the basic logic will be something like:

Parent

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.state = {
        "value": "" // assuming 'value' is a string
    }
}

handleClick(value) {
    this.setState({ "value": value })
}

render() {
    return(
       <ChildComponent
           handleClick={this.handleClick}
           value={this.state.value} />
       <ChildComponent
           handleClick={this.handleClick}
           value={this.state.value} />
       <ChildComponent
           handleClick={this.handleClick}
           value={this.state.value} />
   )
}
```

Child (since you talk about state of a child, setting this up as though it is a stateful component, not a presentational component)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.state = {
        "value": "" // assuming 'value' is a string
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState( {"value": nextProps.value} )
}

handleClick() {
    const value = "Hey here's a value!"
    props.handleClick(value) // call the parent's handleClick
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Set value</button>
        </div>
   )
}
```

But truth be told, I wouldn't even bother setting the state in the child - just set it in the parent and access it via `props`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so...

I'm working on some kind of picker. 
There are 3 components of the same type. Each component stores different state.
States depends on what user typed in input field (combined with react-autosuggest).
User fill up 3 inputs, and choose 1 image that is rendered depends on state.
After user click image, all inputs should be cleared (value is in state).

I made that working but not rly satisfied

and this is combined with redux

Parent

I made a ref to each component and save a instance to his state and pass callback to trigger methods in all child instances.

```
class Parent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.clearAllInputs = this.clearAllInputs.bind(this) // coz callback returns child own props
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            firstChild: this.firstChild.getWrappedInstance(),
            secondChild: this.secondChild.getWrappedInstance(),
            thirdChild: this.thirdChild.getWrappedInstance(),
        })
    }

    clearAllInputs() {

        //call methods from all child instances

        this.state.firstChild.clearInput();
        this.state.secondChild.clearInput();
        this.state.thirdChild.clearInput();
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return(
            <Child ref={ context => this.firstChild = context } clearAllInputs={this.clearAllInputs} ... />
            <Child ref={ context => this.secondChild = context } clearAllInputs={this.clearAllInputs} ... />
            <Child ref={ context => this.thirdChild = context } clearAllInputs={this.clearAllInputs} ... />
        );
    }

    ...

}

class Child extends Component {

    ...

    clearInput() {
        this.setState( { value : '' } );
    }

    render() {
        return(
            ...
            <img ... onClick={ this.props.clearAllInputs } />
        );
    }

}

export default connect(state, null, dispatchers, { withRef: true })(Child);
```